# Ho do add data in the same column?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a df data, and don't know how to add by rows in the same column  those values. How can I do this?

```
   0       [1604966400000, 430124.8064607736]
1       [1605052800000, 430124.8064607736]
2       [1605139200000, 463961.9449876027]
3      [1605225600000, 477763.82229513454]
4       [1605312000000, 751128.5249496251]
                      ...
832     [1676851200000, 497156048.0383911]
833     [1676937600000, 829504410.9065009]
834     [1677024000000, 609236565.5243112]
835     [1677110400000, 304953847.2067599]
836     [1677121974000, 308803127.7273957]
Name: total_volumes, Length: 837, dtype: object
```

Comment: Try `concat` ([link to doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)) and see it meets your need.

Comment: sorry, I must have expressed wrongly ... the data (both) is in the same column .... so I think I should separate it, and after that add it in a new column ... but have tried and nothing ...

Comment: So, you want to split the current column into two columns. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the further information provided in the comment, the goal is to take the data in the current column, split it into two columns, and put them back into the data frame.

One way to do so is to take the current column, convert it into a `numpy` array, and then assign each column of the `numpy` array to the data frame. An example is shown below.

The original `df`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "total_volumes": [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
    }
)

print(df['total_volumes'])
```

```
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
2    [5, 6]
3    [7, 8]
Name: total_volumes, dtype: object
```

After splitting the data

```
import numpy as np

# convert pd series to list first and then to numpy array
data = np.array(df['total_volumes'].to_list())
df['bar'] = data[:, 0]  # assign first column
df['egg'] = data[:, 1]  # assign second column
df.drop('total_volumes', axis=1, inplace=True)  # drop the original column
print(df)
```

```
   bar  egg
0    1    2
1    3    4
2    5    6
3    7    8
```